# Variable is always undefined when called in a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Before I come to my question, here is my Typescript class:

```
export class Info {

    private currentId: number;

    private addToListButton: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor() {
        this.currentId = +(<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("Example")).value;

        this.addToListButton = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("addToList");

        this.registerEvents();
    }

    private registerEvents(): void {
        this.addToListButton.addEventListener("click", (() => this.addToList()));
    }

    private addToList(): void {
        var data: SomeModel;
        data.id = this.currentId;

        // ajax stuff
    }
}
```

My problem is when I want to get the "currentId" for the model, it's always undefined.
The other variable "addToListButton" can I use in the same function without problems.

I can't see what's the problem there.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have debugged the place in the constructor before, there is the variable correctly felt. Therefore, I believe that this line works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `this` in the function `addToList` doesn't refer to the instance of the class `Info` when the function is called here `this.addToListButton.addEventListener("click", (() => this.addToList()));`.

To have `this` refering to the instance, use an arrow function:

```
private const addToList = (): void => { // Arrow function
  var data: SomeModel;
  data.id = this.currentId;

  // ajax stuff
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are some explanations on what arrow functions are.

Answer (score 0):

In the `addToList()` method, the keyword `this` refers to the event context not the `Info` object context.

To use in this manner, you'll need to bind the method to the class. Add this to the constructor:

```
this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
```